# Testing and mocking fetch in async useEffect and async Redux-Saga

Tags: jestjs, fetch, enzyme, redux-saga, react-hooks

I'm testing a functional component, that use React-Hooks and Redux-Saga. I can pass parameters in URL for the component, because they are a login page component.

My URL i pass is 'localhost/access/**parameter**', and when this parameter exists, i need to call a async redux saga, and if the fetch is OK, i put the result in redux-store. When the result is on redux-store, i have a useEffect that verify the result and if is OK, i put her in a input.

I can mock the result with axios, but i'm migrating to use only **fetch**. i mock the fetch, but when i use 
`mount(component)`, provided by enzyme, i do not how to await the redux-saga termine the request and useEffect do your job. I put a console log inside a effect, saga and log the input props to see your **value prop**, but the value is always empty . I tried to use `setImmediate()` and `process.nextTick()`.

Links i use to write the code: [1](https://medium.com/@rishabhsrao/mocking-and-testing-fetch-with-jest-c4d670e2e167),[2](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1587), [3](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/967)

I'm using formik, so they pass some props to me.

**My component**

```
const Login = ({
  setFieldError, errors, response, fetchDomain, location, values, handleChange, handleBlur, setFieldValue, history,
}) => {

   useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUrlDomain() {
      const { pathname } = location;
      const [, , domain] = pathname.split('/');

      if (typeof domain !== 'undefined') {
        await fetchDomain(domain);
      }
    }

    fetchUrlDomain();
  }, [fetchDomain, location]);

   useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof response === 'string') {
      setFieldError('domain', 'Domain not found');
      inputDomain.current.focus();
    } else if (Object.keys(response).length > 0) {
      setFieldValue('domain', response.Domain);
      setFieldError('domain', '');
    }
  }, [response, setFieldValue, setFieldError]);

return (
  <input name="domain" id="domain" value={values.domain} onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} type="text" />
);
}

const LoginFormik = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ domain: '' }),
  enableReinitialize: false,
  validateOnBlur: false,
  validateOnChange: false,
})(Login);

const mapStateToProps = () => ({ });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchDomain: (value) => {
    dispatch(action({}, constants.RESET_RESPONSE_DOMAIN));
    dispatch(action(value, constants.FETCH_DOMAIN_REQUEST));
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginFormik);
```

My Saga

```
export function* fetchDomain(action) {
  const url = yield `${mainUrl}/${action.payload}`;
  try {
    const response = yield fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
    yield put(reduxAction(response , constants.FETCH_DOMAIN_SUCCESS));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(reduxAction(e, constants.FETCH_DOMAIN_FAILURE));
  }
}
```

My Reducer

```
case constants.FETCH_DOMAIN_FAILURE:
  return { ...initialState, response: 'Domain not found' };
case constants.FETCH_DOMAIN_SUCCESS: {
  const { payload } = action;
  return {
    ...initialState,
    id: payload.Id,
    apis: payload.Apis,
    response: payload,
  };
}
case constants.RESET_RESPONSE_DOMAIN:
  return { ...initialState };
```

My Test

```
it('input with fetch only', (done) => {
  const mockSuccessResponse = {
    Id: 'fafafafa',
    Apis: [],
    Domain: 'NAME',
  };
  const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(mockSuccessResponse);
  const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({
    json: () => mockJsonPromise,
  });

  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);

  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LoginForm
        history={{ push: jest.fn() }}
        location={{ pathname: 'localhost/login/Domain' }}
      />
    </Provider>,
  );

  process.nextTick(() => {
    const input = wrapper.find('#domain');
    console.log(input.props());
    expect(input.props().value.toLowerCase()).toBe('name');

    global.fetch.mockClear();
    done();
  });
});
```

I expect my input have value, but he don't. I tried to use [jest-fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) but just don't work, and i want to use native jest methods, no thirty party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say what's wrong with your current code. But want to propose different approach instead.

Currently you are testing both redux part and component's one. It contradicts with unit testing strategy when ideally you should mock everything except module under the test.

So I mean if you focus on testing component itself it'd be way easier(less mocks to create) and more readable. For that you need additionally export unwrapped component(`Login` in your case). Then you can test only its props-vs-render result:

```
it('calls fetchDomain() with domain part of location', () => {
    const fetchDomain = jest.fn();
    const location = { pathName: 'example.com/path/sub' }
    shallow(<Login fetchDomain={fetchDomain} location={location} />);
    expect(fetchDomain).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fetchDomain).toHaveBeenCalledWith('example.com');
});

it('re-calls fetchDomain() on each change of location prop', () => {
    const fetchDomain = jest.fn();
    const location = { pathName: 'example.com/path/sub' }
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login fetchDomain={fetchDomain} location={location} />);
    fetchDomain.mockClear();
    wrapper.setProps({ location: { pathName: 'another.org/path' } });
    expect(fetchDomain).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fetchDomain).toHaveBeenCalledWith('another.org');
});
```

And the same for other cases. See with this approach if you replace `redux` with direct call to `fetch()` or whatever, or if you refactor that data to come from parent instead of reading from redux store you will not need to rewrite tests removing mocks to redux. Sure, you will still need to test redux part but it also can be done in isolation.

PS and there is no profit to `await fetchDomain(...)`  in `useEffect` since you don't use what it returns. `await` does not work like a pause and that code may rather confuse reader.

Comment: Good morning skyboyer. Thanks for your help and your answer. When i write tests to front-end, in first step i test the functionalities of the component/redux/sagas, after this, i'll try to make a complete test, just only mocking the API's call, like a integration test. This approach is wrong? About your answer, i'll try here and post the results, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I cannot say it's wrong way. But testing of component + redux + saga looks to me like near to acceptance testing. And that would be easier to achieve with different tools(Selenium or puppeter).

Comment: Hey skyboyer, thanks, your example help-me, but not solve my problem. Formik give to me a function that change the input, and if i shallow the component without the formik wrapper, the input dont change the value hahaha.

Comment: not sure it's the reason. see you are providing both `value` and `onChange`. also there `ref` is not used so I don't see how that could be affected by Formik. do you use any interm variable like described at https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2139#issuecomment-495947192 ?